# Too many re-renders. Using switch statement with useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an ErrorBox component that is purely displaying the error with the specified attributes. The expected output should be that depending on the `ErrorReason` it will display the associated color, icon and info

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState({})
  switch (ErrorReason) {
    case "wrong-password":
      setStatus({
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
      });
      break;
    case "invalid-email":
      setStatus({
        icon: "cross",
        info: "Invalid email",
        color: "#000"
      });
      break;
    case "too-many-request":
      setStatus({
        icon: "user",
        info: "Too many incorrect requests",
        color: "#bbb"
      });
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={status.icon}
        style={{ color: `${status.color}` }}
      />
      {status.info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How many re-renders upon which events ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're starting with the state `{}` and then immediately modifying it.

You don't need to want *state* here at all. Just use the error reason:

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {
  let icon, info, color;
  switch (ErrorReason) {
    case "wrong-password":
      icon = "lock";
      info = "Incorrect password";
      color = "#fff";
      break;
    case "invalid-email":
      icon = "cross";
      info = "Invalid email";
      color = "#000";
      break;
    case "too-many-request":
      icon = "user";
      info = "Too many incorrect requests";
      color = "#bbb";
      break;
    default:
      // Must throw here
      throw new Error(`Invalid ErrorReason: ${ErrorReason}`);
  }

  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={icon}
        style={{ color: `${color}` }}
      />
      {info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

But if you *did* need state, you'd do the `switch` first and then use the value as the initial value of the state:

```
// If you needed state for some reason (you don't below)
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {

  let initialStatus;
  switch (ErrorReason) {
    case "wrong-password":
      initialStatus = {
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
      };
      break;
    case "invalid-email":
      initialStatus = {
        icon: "cross",
        info: "Invalid email",
        color: "#000"
      };
      break;
    case "too-many-request":
      initialStatus = {
        icon: "user",
        info: "Too many incorrect requests",
        color: "#bbb"
      };
      break;
    default:
      // Must throw here
      throw new Error(`Invalid ErrorReason: ${ErrorReason}`);
  }
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(initialStatus);

  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={status.icon}
        style={{ color: `${status.color}` }}
      />
      {status.info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

I don't think I'd use a `switch` to map the `ErrorReason` to error information at all, I'd use a map (or an object created with `Object.create(null)`):

```
const statusInfoMap = new Map([
  [
    "wrong-password",
    {
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
    }
  ],
  [
    "invalid-email",
    {
      icon: "cross",
      info: "Invalid email",
      color: "#000"
    }
  ],
  [
    "too-many-request",
    {
      icon: "user",
      info: "Too many incorrect requests",
      color: "#bbb"
    }
  ]
]);
```

Then the component is just:

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {
  const status = statusInfoMap.get(ErrorReason);
  if (!status) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid ErrorReason: ${ErrorReason}`);
  }

  const {icon, color, info} = status;
  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={icon}
        style={{ color: `${color}` }}
      />
      {info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

const statusInfoMap = new Map([
  [
    "wrong-password",
    {
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
    }
  ],
  [
    "invalid-email",
    {
      icon: "cross",
      info: "Invalid email",
      color: "#000"
    }
  ],
  [
    "too-many-request",
    {
      icon: "user",
      info: "Too many incorrect requests",
      color: "#bbb"
    }
  ]
]);

const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {
  const status = statusInfoMap.get(ErrorReason);
  if (!status) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid ErrorReason: ${ErrorReason}`);
  }

  const {icon, color, info} = status;
  return (
    <div >
       icon: {icon}, color: {color}, info: {info}
    </div>
  );
};

const errors = [
  "wrong-password",
  "invalid-email",
  "too-many-request",
];
const Example = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const error = errors[index];
    
    const onClick = useCallback(() => {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }, [index]);

    return (
        <div>
            <ErrorBox ErrorReason={error} />
            {index < errors.length - 1
            ? <input type="button" value="Next" onClick={onClick} />
            : <input type="button" value="Start Again" onClick={() => setIndex(0)} />
            }
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you need state for something you haven't shown:

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {
  const initialStatus = statusInfoMap.get(ErrorReason);
  if (!initialStatus) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid ErrorReason: ${ErrorReason}`);
  }
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(initialStatus);

  const {icon, color, info} = status;
  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={icon}
        style={{ color: `${color}` }}
      />
      {info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Any reason why you opt in to not use state? for the re-render for any changes and just used variables to store the values. Example would be the answer below. Would this be a more optimized approach?

Comment: @Freddy. - State is for something that changes within the component's control. There's nothing in the component in the question that *changes* state, it just derives its rendering information from the prop it receives. ***If*** the component has a reason to call `setStatus` *other* than as shown in the question, then you might use state. But otherwise, the component has no need of it.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I guess since it is only a display component I will opt out state.

Comment: @Freddy. - That would be the usual thing. :-) Also, I realized after looking at the other answer you referred to, that answer has other issues (an initial render with `undefined` for all the render info).

Answer (score -1):

You should perform state update only when `ErrorReason` changes. In this scenario use `useEffect` hook and add `ErrorReason` as dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
 switch (ErrorReason) {
    case "wrong-password":
      setStatus({
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
      });
      break;
    case "invalid-email":
      setStatus({
        icon: "cross",
        info: "Invalid email",
        color: "#000"
      });
      break;
    case "too-many-request":
      setStatus({
        icon: "user",
        info: "Too many incorrect requests",
        color: "#bbb"
      });
      break;
  }
}, [ErrorReason])
```

Update:
To avoid local state and variables.

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {

  const getData = () => {
switch (ErrorReason) {
    case "wrong-password":
      return ({
        icon: "lock",
        info: "Incorrect password",
        color: "#fff"
      });
    case "invalid-email":
      return ({
        icon: "cross",
        info: "Invalid email",
        color: "#000"
      });
    case "too-many-request":
      return ({
        icon: "user",
        info: "Too many incorrect requests",
        color: "#bbb"
      });
  }}


  return (
    <div >
       <Icon
        type={status.icon}
        style={{ color: `${status.color}` }}
      />
      {getData().info} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: There's no need for state at all, and this will cause an extra unnecessary render when the component is first created.

Comment: Why you assume that `ErrorReason` is not "changing / updating" data?

Comment: I don't. It's irrelevant. Again: The component derives its rendering information solely from the prop. So there's no reason for state. And again, the above will initially render unnecessarily with `info`, `color`, and `icon` all having the values `undefined`, then render again with the correct values.

Comment: Even with local variables you have to use `useEffect` hook to reassign that variables. You assignments will perform only once. Or you may create a function to return that values and call from JSX.

Comment: Citation? Example? I'm happy to learn something new. But having the component rendering purely from props is incredibly boring, standard behavior.

Comment: Yes I agree, there is no need to use state in this case! But having a local variable is not the best way to do this. I would create a function and pass `ErrorReason` and call from JSX.

Comment: There's no harm in using locals for this at all. But yes, isolating the mapping of `ErrorReason` => status object is something you might put in a function if it's done in more than one place. If it's only done in the one place, there's no need to.

Comment: Yes, I think this is just a style of coding.

Comment: All due respect, 1. The `useEffect` version at the top is still incorrect. 2. The updated version underneath has an undefined variable, `status`, being used in the render, and there's no reason for `getData` to be *inside* the component and recreated every time.